# Why does a row inside a fluid container overflow on the x-axis?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4, overflow

I am adding a footer to my website. When I add it it makes the website overflow on the x-axis. Removing the 15px margins in the .row isn't an option because i would have to redo all the css

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<footer style="margin-top:20px;background-color:lightgrey">
    <div class="container-fluid" style="max-width:100%; margin:0px">
        <div class="row" style="margin:0px;width:100%">
            <div class="col-8" style="padding-bottom:10px !important; padding:40px">
                <h4 style="margin-top: 10px">Om</h4>
                <p class="text-muted" style="margin-top:7px">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vestibulum placerat malesuada leo. Vestibulum rutrum erat non diam feugiat pulvinar.
    Nam sit amet aliquam nibh. Vestibulum sed consequat elit. Ut sodales justo sit amet iaculis venenatis. Curabitur fermentum magna id nunc ullamcorper consectetur.
    Cras quis odio quis elit aliquet vulputate in nec nulla. Donec placerat bibendum ligula eget fringilla. Quisque sem ligula, sodales at est vitae, consectetur tempor justo.
                </p>
            </div>
            <div class="col-2" style="padding-bottom:10px !important;padding:40px">
                <h4 style="margin-top: 10px">Hurtige links</h4>
                <li style="list-style-type: none;">
                    <a href="/upload" style="margin-bottom:10px">Upload</a>
                </li>
                <li style="list-style-type: none;">
                    <a href="/profil/{{ current_user.bruger_url_id }}">Min profil</a>
                </li>
                <li style="list-style-type: none;">
                    <a href="/">Hjem</a>
                </li>
            </div>
            <div class="col-2" style="padding-bottom:10px !important;padding:40px; padding-left: 0px !important">
                <h4 style="margin-top: 10px">Ligegyldige links</h4>
                <li style="list-style-type: none;">
                    <a href="/betingelser">Betingelser</a>
                </li>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="container-fluid" style="width:100%">
        <div class="row" style="width:100%;background-color:lightgrey">
            <div class="col-12" style="padding-top:0px !important;padding-bottom: 0px !important;padding:40px">
                <hr>
                <p>Copyright &copy; 2019 All Rights Reserved by Studii</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</footer>
```

Comment: Why would you have to re-code all of the CSS to remove the margin? Try adding the class ```mx-0``` to the row to remove the margin?

Comment: Don't change the margins

Comment: Inline styles are hideous, and if you're overriding Bootstrap that often something has gone terribly wrong.

Comment: It doesn't seem like it's overflowing: https://jsfiddle.net/isherwood/zxrps35w/

Comment: Other random tips: List items must be children of list elements (`ul` or `ol`). List with one item probably shouldn't be lists.

Comment: Just to try and be helpful, here's your markup with all the inline styles removed and some CSS in place. Notice how nothing overflows. https://jsfiddle.net/isherwood/zxrps35w/9/

Comment: I also use jinja2 so when i include the footer.html file in ther header.html it overflows, but when I remove it dosen't, so that dosen't make sense to me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> container-fluid was originally taken out of Bootstrap 3.0, but added
>   back in 3.1.1
>
> To fix this, you can either:
>
> Use the newer version of Bootstrap style sheet
>
> [Demo with New Style Sheet in Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/KyleMit/p23EB/7/) Or add in the class yourself
>
> The .row adds a 15px margin to the left and right. Since
>   `.container-fluid` fills up 100% of the screen width, the extra margin
>   space causes overflow issues.
>
> To fix this, you need to add padding to .container-fluid class
>
> ```
> .container-fluid {
>     padding-right: 15px;
>     padding-left: 15px;
>     margin-right: auto;
>     margin-left: auto;
> }
> ```
>
> [Demo with Custom container class in Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/KyleMit/p23EB/8/)